# Should web sites have their own authentication?

Tags: website-design, authentication

If I am designing a web site that interacts with the same user over time via email or other messaging mediums, should I allow account creation on the web site using a traditional username/password/email combination, or is that outmoded at this point and I only need to provide logins via an identity provider such as Facebook, Google, or both?

I had originally planned to do account creation, but heard a bit from people who haven't created an account in years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what your site is for. If the site is for something specific that you might not want shared (or known) socially then you may find Facebook/Google/Twitter logins might not cut it.

There's also a generational angle. I know that many in my parents generation will not sign in with a 3rd party oauth Login.

1. Because they just don't get it
2. Often they fear (legit or otherwise) that things will get messed up if they use Facebook to access another site

Even for those that understand the tech, there can be fears and you may lose a user over it. E.g. If I have to use Twitter/Facebook to login somewhere and they don't explicitly indicate that they are NOT requesting permission to post on my behalf... I will bail instantly.

If you do use oauth logins from social media sites I'd highly recommend disabling all features except pure authentication.